# How can I create "duplicated index patterns" in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I'm using kibana 7.10.1.
I need it to use different 'time fields' for each index pattern. Is this possible to set multiple time fields for same index ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pick any `date` (or `date_nanos`) field as the primary time field in an index pattern. Screenshot from the second page when creating it:

[image]

`@timestamp` is just a convention. Though you will need to create a different index pattern for each combination of index(es) and primary time field.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply. Can we create duplicate elasticsearch index with same data and different name from existing elasticsearch index ??

Comment: This is about Kibana index patterns, where you should be able to create multiple ones even for the same indices. Not sure I follow the duplication of an Elasticsearch index — that shouldn't be necessary here (though it is generally possible with Elasticsearch's API).